# Is it possible to translate words "day", "week", "month", "year" with pure js in modern browsers (Intl API)?

Tags: javascript, intl

Task is to display subscription price like `5$ / month` in different locales.

I can manage price part with [`Intl`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl) nicely, but stuck with time period translating part.
I can use my own translation strings, but would prefer to use default `Intl` version if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Intl.DisplayNames`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DisplayNames) with type [`datetimefield`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DisplayNames/DisplayNames#using_type_datetimefield) from the [Intl API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl).

```js
const trans = (translate, locale = 'en') => {
  return new Intl.DisplayNames(locale, { type: 'dateTimeField' }).of(translate);
}

for (lang of [ 'en', 'nl', 'fr', 'zh-Hant' ]) {
  console.log(`3$ / ${trans('month', lang)}`);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/dayjs@1.8.21/dayjs.min.js"></script>
```

```
3$ / month
3$ / maand
3$ / mois
3$ / 月
```

---

This api is capable of translating almost every date/time strings.
Overview of supported/translatable values:

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| day | hour | minute | second |
| year | month | quarter |  |
| weekOfYear | weekday | era | dayPeriod |

Comment: Working nice in Chrome and Firefox, but exploded in Safari 14.1.2 with ```RangeError: type must be either "language", "region", "script", or "currency"```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `DisplayNames` method and set `type` = `'dateTimeField'`

**example:**

```
const dn = new Intl.DisplayNames('pt', {type: 'dateTimeField'});
console.log(dn.of('era')); // logs 'era'
console.log(dn.of('year')); // logs 'ano'
console.log(dn.of('month')); // logs 'mês'
console.log(dn.of('quarter')); // logs 'trimestre'
console.log(dn.of('weekOfYear')); // logs 'semana'
console.log(dn.of('weekday')); // logs 'dia da semana'
console.log(dn.of('dayPeriod')); // logs 'AM/PM'
console.log(dn.of('day')); // logs 'dia'
console.log(dn.of('hour')); // logs 'hora'
console.log(dn.of('minute')); // logs 'minuto'
console.log(dn.of('second')); // logs 'segundo'
```

source https://docs.w3cub.com/javascript/global_objects/intl/displaynames/displaynames

Comment: This is also my answer, [from 5 minutes ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70542380/5625547)...

Comment: I was writing the answer and didn't see your answer, no problem